# How to set the distance my character can dash?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to give my character the mechanic of dashing but I want to set the distance it can dash. Right now it works fine but I want it to feel nicer. It freezes the y position while dashing, and it removes collisions so you can dash through walls/avoid incoming damage. The only problem is that it dashes depending on speed, which means if I make the speed higher, the character dashes further away.

How should I go about restricting the length of the dash so that if I increase the dash speed it just goes faster within that distance, rather than further?

Here is my code:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
private BoxCollider2D coll;

//Dashing variables
[SerializeField] private float dashDuration = 0.5f;
[SerializeField] private float dashSpeed = 15.0f;

public void Dash()
{
    StartCoroutine(DashRoutine());
}

IEnumerator DashRoutine()
{
    movementAllowed = false;
    coll.isTrigger = true;

    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY; //Freeze y position while dashing

    if(rb.velocity.x < 0)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-dashSpeed, transform.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dashSpeed, transform.position.y);
    }

    Debug.Log("Im dashing!");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashDuration);
    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
    coll.isTrigger = false;
    movementAllowed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speed, Distance, Time formulae:

`S = D / T`
`D = S * T`
`T = D / S`

In Context:

`dashSpeed = dashDistance / dashDuration`
`dashDistance = dashSpeed * dashDuration`
`dashDuration = dashDistance / dashSpeed`

To keep the distance of the dash the same while increasing speed, you need to decrease the dash time.  You can determine the dash time by solving the formula for time `T=D/S`

eg. `dashDuration = dashDistance / dashSpeed`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76223356/7111561):

Well instead of waiting a fixed `dashDuration` you can rather go by the distance traveled (or combine both and stop dashing on whichever finishes first)

```
...

[SerializeField]
private float maxDashDistance;

...

private IEnumerator DashRoutine()
{
    ...

    Debug.Log("Im dashing!");

    var startPosition = rb.position;
    // it is slightly cheaper to compare square magnitude
    var sqrMaxDistance = maxDashDistance * maxDashDistance;
    
    // iterates until either the dashDuration or the maxDashDistance is exceeded
    for (var timePassed = 0f; 
         timePassed < dashDuration && (rb.position - startPosition).sqrMagnitude < sqrMaxDistance; 
         timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.None;
    coll.isTrigger = false;

    // assuming this ensures you stop moving with the dashSpeed
    movementAllowed = true;
}
```

or if the `for` loop condition looks too ugly to you you can also drag it in like

```
for (var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < dashDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
{
    if((rb.position - startPosition).sqrMagnitude >= sqrMaxDistance) break;

    yield return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully I can help out :) The issue is that you're simply setting the *velocity* of the rigidBody; Thus, if the *velocity is greater*, the object will travel *further*. A better approach would be to somehow smoothly move from the current position to a desired distance; In other words, we could **linearly interpolate**, or lerp. You can read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html). You can use the rigidbody's position for the start position, and then get the end position by adding the current position with some vector (distance).